# Highest point between Stochastic oversold and its subsequent

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I want to mark the highest point between Stochastic oversold and its subsequent and highest point between Stochastic overbought and its subsequent. The code that I write is not working as intended. The code should have plot at the offseted location but it does not work. Since I am new to pinescript, I am not sure that the offset value can be dynamic value or not.

```
//@version=4
study("Stochastic Signal Generator", shorttitle="SSG", overlay=true)

// Calculate Stochastic %K
k = sma(stoch(close, high, low, 9),3)
obLevel = 80
osLevel = 20

// Trigger variables
var osTrigger = 0
var obTrigger = 0
var ostCount = 0
var obtCount = 0
osLooklength = 0
obLooklength = 0
highLocation = 0
lowLocation = 0
barLocation = 0
bool upFractal = false
bool downFractal = false

// Timestamp variables
var osTimestamps = array.new_int(0)
var obTimestamps = array.new_int(0)

// High/low tracking
var highestHighs = array.new_float(0)
var lowestLows = array.new_float(0)

// Declare plothigh as a series variable
var float plothigh = na

// Check for oversold/overbought conditions and set triggers
if osTrigger == 0 and k<osLevel
    osTrigger := 1
    obTrigger := 0
    ostCount := ostCount + 1
    barLocation := bar_index
    array.push(osTimestamps, bar_index)
    var float hHigh = 0.0
    if ostCount > 1
        osLooklength := array.get(osTimestamps, array.size(osTimestamps) - 1) - array.get(osTimestamps, array.size(osTimestamps) - 2)
        for i = 0 to osLooklength - 1
            if high[osLooklength - i] > hHigh
                hHigh := high[osLooklength - i]
                highLocation := osLooklength - i
                
        osLooklength := 0
        hHigh := 0

else if obTrigger == 0 and k>obLevel
    osTrigger := 0
    obTrigger := 1
    obtCount := obtCount + 1
    barLocation := bar_index
    array.push(obTimestamps, bar_index)
    var float lLow = 0.0
    if obtCount > 1
        obLooklength := array.get(obTimestamps, array.size(obTimestamps) - 1) - array.get(obTimestamps, array.size(obTimestamps) - 2)
        for i = 0 to obLooklength - 1
            if low[obLooklength - i] < lLow
                lLow := low[obLooklength - i]
                lowLocation := obLooklength - i
                
        obLooklength := 0
        lLow := 9999999

if highLocation > 0
    upFractal := true

if lowLocation > 0
    downFractal := true
    
plotshape(upFractal, style=shape.triangleup,   location=location.abovebar, offset=highLocation, color=#009688, size = size.small)
plotshape(downFractal, style=shape.triangledown,   location=location.belowbar, offset=lowLocation, color=#009688, size = size.small)
```

Please help me offset the plot. I do not mind if you entirely change the logic. Thanks